# Where can I find pressure-temperature diagrams or phase diagrams for various substances on the internet ? (and for free)

Tags: material-science, phase-transition, phase-diagram

In this particular case, I want to investigate making liquid nitrogen.

My compressor will only go to 400 PSI, so I want to know what temperature nitrogen will turn liquid at 400 PSI (and really 350 PSI is probably where I want it to not prematurely burn my compressor !)

But I've been searching "pressure-temperature diagram" and "phase change diagram" and "nitrogen triple point" on google and I'm getting surprisingly terrible results !

Either they only show a narrow range of values, or they lack units, or I'm not really sure it really is the correct graph for nitrogen. Just terrible sources !?

Why is this so hard, is someone making lots of money to keep these diagrams behind a paywall ?

Surely science knows the phase diagram from millitorrs to gigapascals and from microkelvins to the temperature at the core of the Sun.

So where is this information hidden ?

Comment: Not sure how thoroughly you seem to have search, the first diagram for "nitrogen phase diagram" has all the info you need, at least roughly, to show you'd still need around $-200\; C^{\circ}$ to get gaseous Nitrogen to turn liquid at that pressure.

Comment: That's why I was hesitant to include an example, I don't just want the answer to my particular substance. I'm searching for a free and trustworthy resource with all of the pressure temperature diagrams. I also found google results and they seem to indicate -150C to -120C. Not really useful if I can't tell which ones are wrong !